# After using the Deferred Acceptance algorithm, is this matching stable?

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, matching-theory

All profiles are strictly preferred. I have a set of students (s) and teachers (t). I have to come up with a construct where the matching is stable and the algorithm gives two outcomes that are different. The students in S should also prefer the outcome of the student-proposal and the teachers in T should prefer the outcome of the teacher-proposal. Have I done this correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both of the matching are stable. Instability requires both of the participants to be happier with an alternative match, but from the perspective of the students as proposers $s2$ was already rejected by $t3$, so they can not be happier with anyone other than $t1$ and $t1$ had no other offers. It shows that there can be more than one stable matching and as can be the case the matches are optimal from the proposers prospective.

Comment: Thank you so much!